# Confusion with DBCP connection pooling and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to get Multi-Threading working in my Java web application and it seems like no matter what I try I run into some sort of issues with connection pooling.

My current process is that I have am looping through all my departments and processing them, which finally generates a display.  This takes time, so I want to spawn a thread for each department and have them process concurrently.

After alot of time of first figuring out how to get my hibernate session to stay open in a thread to prevent the lazy initializion loading errors, I finally had the solution of creating a Spring bean of my Thread class, and creating a new instance of that bean for each thread.  I have tried 2 different versions

1) I directly inject the DAO classes into the Bean.  FAILED - After loading the page a few times I would get **"Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object"** for each thread and the app would crash.

2) Ok so then I tried injecting the spring `SessionFactory` into my bean, then create new instances of my DAO and set it with the `SessionFactory`.  My DAO objects all extend `HibernateDaoSupport`.  FAILED - After loading the page a few times I would get **"too many connections"** error messages.

Now what I am confused about is that my `SessionFactory` bean is a singleton which I understand to mean that it is a single Object that is shared throughout the Spring container.  If that is true then why does it appear like each Thread is creating a new connection when it should just be sharing that single instance?  It appears that all my connection pool is getting filled up and I don't understand why.  Once the threads are done, all the connections that were created should be released but there not.  I even tried running a close() operation on the injected `SessionFactory` but that has no effect.  I tried limiting how many threads run concurrently at 5, hoping that would cause not so many connections to be created at one time but no luck.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I am not sure what.  Am I taking the wrong approach entirely in trying to get my hibernate `Session` into my `Thread`s?  Am I somehow not managing my connection pool properly?  any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

More info I thought of: My process creates about 25 threads total, which are run 5 at a time.  I am able to refresh my page about 3 times before I start getting the errors.  So apparently each refresh creates and holds on to a bunch of connections.

Here is my spring config file:

```
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">

....

<!-- Purposely put big values in here trying to figure this issue out 
since my standard smaller values didn't help.  These big values Fail just the same -->

    <property name="maxActive"><value>500</value></property>
    <property name="maxIdle"><value>500</value></property>
    <property name="minIdle"><value>500</value></property>
    <property name="maxWait"><value>5000</value></property>
    <property name="removeAbandoned"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="validationQuery"><value>select 0</value></property>
</bean>

<!--Failed attempt #1 -->
<bean id="threadBean" class="controller.manager.ManageApprovedFunds$TestThread" scope="prototype">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="dao" /></property>
    </bean>

<!--Failed attempt #2 -->
<bean id="threadBean" class="manager.ManageApprovedFunds$TestThread" scope="prototype">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory" /></property>
    </bean>
```

Java code:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(Department dept : getDepartments()) {
    TestThread t = (TestThread)springContext.getBean("threadBean");
    t.init(dept, form, getSelectedYear());
    taskExecutor.submit(t);
}

taskExecutor.shutdown();

public static class TestThread extends HibernateDaoSupport implements Runnable, ApplicationContextAware {
        private ApplicationContext appContext;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
                throws BeansException {
            this.appContext = arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                MyDAO dao = new MyDAO();
                dao.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());

                //SOME READ OPERATIONS

                getSessionFactory().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to be jumping through these hoops to get basic DBCP working.  Have a look at http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-configure-tomcat-dbcp-connection-pool-pooling-postgres  Also having `TestThread` as a static seems a bit strange.

Comment: @ScaryWombat getting basic DBCP working isn't the problem, it works great...until i introduce concurrency at which point my connection pool gets sucked dry.  Thats what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.  Why would basic DBCP not be concurrent out-of-the-box?  What is the point of having multiple connections, if you can only use one?

Comment: well apparently I can use 500 based on my config, and I'm still running out when i use concurrency.  25 total threads, 5 threads at a time.  I'm trying to figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you shouldn't try to share a single hibernate `Session` between threads. Hibernate sessions, nor the entity objects, are threadsafe and that can lead to some suprising problems. [Here](http://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/sharing-hibernate-entities-between-threads/) and [here]3[] is a small but nice read there is also some value in the comments. Basically don't try to share a `Session` between threads.

There is also another problem as the whole transaction management is based around `ThreadLocal` objects, the same goes for obtaining the current session and underlying JDBC connection. Now trying to spawn threads will lead to suprising problems, one of them would be connection pool starvation. (Note: don't open too many connections, more information [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing)).

Next to not to opening to much connections you should be aware of starting to many threads. A Thread is bound to a cpu (or core if you have multiple cores). Adding to many threads might lead to heavy sharing of a single cpu/core between to many threads. This can kill your performance instead of increasing it.

In short IMHO your approach is wrong, each thread should simply read the entity it cares about, do its thing and commit the transaction. I would suggest using something like [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) for this instead of inventing your own mechanism. (Although if it is simple enough I would probably go for it).

Comment: As I read it he is not sharing the `Session` but the `SessionFactory` which is the right way to do things.

Comment: That is not what I read :). To quote @raymond-holguin `After alot of time of first figuring out how to get my hibernate session to stay open in a thread` which imho means he is trying to share a session. If that isn't the case his approach is still wrong and he should just use basic tx configuration (which you can achieve without your own threads by simply using `@Async` together with `@Transactional` on your handling method).

Comment: If it is "simple enough", use the idioms documented in the Hibernate manual chapter [Transactions and Concurrency](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html).

Comment: @M.Deinum - Perhaps my inexperience was leading me to use `Session` and `SessionFactory` interchangeably, but I meant I was sharing the `SessionFactory` and I thought my code reflected that with how I am injecting the `sessionFactory` into my runnable bean.  As for performance, before I run out of connections its great as I am seeing over 75% increase in page loading time so its worth it.  "each thread should simply read the entity it cares about"  That is what I am trying to do.  These threads are dong READ-ONLY processes to prepare the data concurrently instead of sequentially for the view

Comment: @Raymond Holguin - trying to load stuff for one view using different sessions might be counter-productive, since each `Session` uses it's own first-level-cahce, so you might end up loading several entities multiple times instead of one time when done from one `Session`!

Comment: @piet.t Yea i get that, that't why my initial attempts at this were to share the `Session` (my DAO's and Service classes) between threads.  But i believe due to me using the `OpenSessionInView` filter, I was getting "session closed" or Lazy initialization exceptions in my Threads...so that didn't work too well.

Answer (score 1):

A database connection is not associated with the `SessionFactory` but with the `Session`. To get your handling correct you have to take care of the following:

- Only create one instance of `SessionFactory` (per persistence context) - but you are doing this already
- Don't `close()` the `SessionFactory` - it's lifetime should end when the application dies - that is at undeployment or server-shutdown.
- Make sure to always `close()` your `Session` - you use one database connection per open `Session` and if these don't get closed you are leaking connections.